# Need to simulate series of keyboard key events in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

Since i am beginner in shell scripting and don't know much about the simulating keyboard keys in scripting.

In one of my script i need to run, `bq init` after this it asks series of questions which involves keyboard events like pressing `yes/no` after pressing `yes` again it asks `yes or no` then it asks to enter the number like `1 or 2`.

I can manage pressing 1st keyboard key event just by running 
`echo "y" | big init` but for later questions/keys i am clueless.
can anyone help with this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. This way may seem intuitive (a *"heredoc"*):

```
yourScript << EOF
bq init
yes
no
maybe
1
2
EOF
```

Or this may appeal to you (a *"compound statement"*):

```
{ echo "yes"; echo "no"; echo "maybe"; echo "1"; } | yourScript
```

Or, the same spelled out line by line:

```
{ 
   echo "yes"
   echo "no"
   echo "maybe"
   echo "1"
} | yourScript
```

Or like this with `printf`:

```
printf "%s\n" "yes" "no" "maybe" "1" | yourScript
```

Comment: @cdarke As Homer Simpson might say, "D'oh". Thank you - I have improved it.

Comment: I tried with your solutions for my another script and it worked. But for the above script i am still facing the problem. Can we introduce some delays between it?

Comment: Sure, you can do `{ echo "yes"; sleep 1; echo "no"; } | yourScript`

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe your input to the program.

```
your_program <<< $'yes\nno\nyour_name\n'
```

You can read more from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings)

Answer (score 0):

A right tool for the job like that is [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)

> Expect is a program that "talks" to other interactive programs according to a script. Following the script, Expect knows what can be expected from a program and what the correct response should be.

Your script might look something like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn "./myscript.sh"

expect "First question ?" 
send "y\r"

expect "Second question ?"
send "2\r"

interact
```

This will spawn "myscript.sh", wait for it to ask the "First question ?" and reply with "y",
then wait for the "Second question ?" and reply with "2".