# Interacting with Linux Command Line Applications

Tags: python, linux, shell, command, line

So, I'm trying to automate going through a python application menu that runs on Linux through the command line. I know what commands I need to enter to go through the menu, but can't seem to figure out how to get a shell script to do what I want. Instead, it waits until the application closes to finish the script. For example:

My shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

./App.py
echo '1'
echo '2'
echo '3'
```

What I expect to happen

```
[adminuser@localhost BASH]$ ./auto.sh
Welcome to App.py!
Enter 1 to continue or 2 to exit: 1

Enter 2 to continue or 3 to exit: 2
```

etc...

What happens instead is that I have to continue through the menu myself then it outputs all my echos when the app terminates.

One note here is that I can't install any libraries that don't come installed in Ubuntu. This computer is not networked and cannot interact with any magnetic media for security reasons. What are my options?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46193408/2836621

Answer (score 0):

Your script should be as below:

```
(echo -e "1\n2\n3") | python App.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a "here-doc" -

```
app.py<<DONE
1
2
3
DONE
```

But I hate those. Throw your expected responses into a text file and execute with stdin redirected from that.

```
printf "1\n2\n3\n">response.in # I assume it would be a little more complex
App.py << response.in          # reads response.in as input
```

Then you can even have various sets of responses in response.1, response.2, etc.